# Use Facebook Android SDK with multiple activities

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, android-activity

I'm developing an android app that uses the Facebook SDK, and has 3 activities: Splash, Main and ContentView. In the splash activity it shows the "Log In with Facebook" button, and as soon as the user authenticates and is logged in, the app destroys the Splash activity and shows the Main activity.

On the Main activity I can post on my wall, but for that I need publishing privileges, but when I ask to extend the privileges it gives me an error: "Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.".

I think it's due to the fact that the splash activity in which I created the uilifecycle has been destroyed, because I'm using a Facebook singleton and using only one `UiLifecycleHelper`. Is there a way to refresh the current activity of the uilifecycle? Or i have to create a new uilifecycle for each activity?

Answer (score 0):

I trying creating an uilifecyclehelper for every activity and now it works !